# Apache Storm bolt to bolt message stop or are flaky

Tags: apache-storm

Spout -> Bolt1 -> Bolt2 -> Bolt3 -> Ack orginalID (free up message on queue)

The basic topology seems to work for several minutes but at some point the message do not get either sent or consumed and the bolt is never called. I cannot tell if the java thread just dies as there is no exceptions in the logs or any indication that there is something wrong.

Apache storm .92 or .95 both have the same results for me.

I have been programming storm for a couple of years and have never seen this....

Comment: Did you check all topology, worker, supervisor and nimbus logs for error messages? As you mention "ack" as last step I assume you enables fault-tolerance. What is your "max.spout.pending" value? Do you have a bottleneck in you pipeline (use Storm UI to observe if all bolt can keep up processing there input tuples)?

Comment: @Don Are you sure the spout does not run out of tuples to emit? if one of your bolts crashes with some "unknown exception" you should be able to see tuples failing in the spout by timeout.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax the max spout pending, does not have any influence in the observed behavior. As soon one tuple is fully processed another can be emitted.

Comment: Well, the idea about "max.spout.pending" was that the source stops to emit tuples if tuple do not get acknowledge. If the timeout value is high, it might seem as that the topology is frozen until the first timeout ticks in...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since my previous response got removed, I will try again just once. 
We have seen a similar behavior, especially with heavy loads. Turned out it was due to a slow bolt. As a result,  this slow process was filling up the queue (that usually would take several hours) and at some point, when queue size was high enough, storm would stop processing completely.

Comment: I was going to mark this as "not an answer", but then I noticed this suggestion in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer". So, thanks for contributing your research. Please let us know if you discover any other insights.